# Windows Server 2016: Restoring from back-up (2012 r2)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016

Trying to restore from back up on a Gen8 Microserver running Server 2016, from a offsite 2012 r2 back up, It won't see the back-up I am assuming that server back ups are non backwards compatible,

Running the back-up in a hyper-v would be best solution?

Comment: managing Hyper-V VM's backup is much easier and yes, it will be a best solution